# Visual Studio Go To / Navigate To / Search Solution Explorer - does not search on file path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I don't know if this happened in the latest update or that I accidently hit a shortcut, but when I try **Go To** (CTRL+Comma) the keywords don't filter on the path of the file anymore.

This is a big problem because a lot of Html files are called i.e. Index.cshtml but are in a relevant folder.

```
Areas\Competitions\Views\Graph\Index.cshtml
Areas\Competitions\Views\Teams\Index.cshtml
Areas\Competitions\Views\Athletes\Index.cshtml
```

When I search for **"index graph html"** it returns empty. Is this a newly introduced bug/feature or did I accidently hit some strange setting?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found that it searches for *OR* the path *OR* the file name.

I have version **VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.3+26730.12**. Can anyone tell me if they have this version and also this bug?

I can't download any older versions from the website.

I've filled in a bug report with Microsoft, but they just tell me that this 'issue will not be addressed in the upcoming release'. After that no response anymore.

As this is a huge productivity killer I need to know if I need to look for alternatives.

Comment: I have version 15.3.4 and can confirm it is a problem for me also

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, then I know I have to stop looking for a hidden setting or something machine related. Please upvote also the report I added on VS 'Report a problem': **Go To / Navigate To does not search on file path**

Comment: I found in the Navigate To box if I press f and then type the name of the controller I can at least get an alphabetical list of the files and select the one I need…

Answer (score 3):

To filter your files in Visual Studio, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and other alternatives that are:

- Filter your files with path by pressing shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> will open VS's CMD and then type **"open  youfilename"** like:

  [image]
- Use hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> in **Solution Explorer** search bar or you can simply click on it and type searched keywords.

  [image]
- Install a add-in [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) in your VS and by installing you can analyze or filter your code or files.

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> a popup will appear and you can start searching there [like](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_File.html):
    [image]

Comment: Hi @Asif.Ali, thanks for your answer. I know these options but except the CMD window the other ones don't work like expected anymore since the last update **VS2017 15.3.3+26730.12**. They don't filter on path and filename - only path **or** filename. Making it unusuable in large projects.

Comment: @DirkBoer I have edited my answer, for more functionality you can perform third step.

Comment: thanks for your extended answer - as I can see in the comment on the question (and the recent upvotes) it is actually a bug that is recently introduced. I don't want to install Resharper (for now) for this functionality :) thanks for your time for answering!

Comment: I have first upvote to your question :) and **ReSharper** provides you extra debugging, performance and code analysis functionalities in VS.

Comment: Tnx for the upvote, Asif! I know Resharper has extra functionality, but in general I'm not missing it atm, and especially I'm not in the situation atm to pay 4 subscriptions of 300 per year for me and my coworkers :) it's apparently a bug they introduced in the latest VS, and I hope they fix it soon

Answer (score 0):

This probably has been fixed for a while now. But I can confirm that it works in visual studio 2022 by doing the following

1. ctrl + ,
2. then type "f index graph html"

Or

1. Ctrl + ,
2. ctrl + shift + T
3. then next to the "f" type "index graph html"

Or

1. Ctrl + ,
2. Click on "Files" icon
3. then next to the "f" type "index graph html"